# How can I use POST method in ROR app on Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, heroku

I've created simple ROR app on Heroku's server and I want to **add product** using RUBY's script:

> require 'rubygems'
>   require 'rest_client'
>
> RestClient.post 'http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products/new', 
>   :title => 'TESTTESTTEST', :description => "MYTESTTESTTESTTEST",
>   :image_url => "TESTTESTNULL.jpg", :price => 4.50

There's my page:

> http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products/new

When I run my script it gives me an error:

> ruby postEasy.rb 
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in
>   `return!': 404 Resource Not Found (RestClient::ResourceNotFound)  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in`
>   process_result'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in
>   `transmit'    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in`start'   from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in
>   `transmit'    from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in`
>   execute'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in
>   `execute'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient.rb:72:in`
>   post'    from postEasy.rb:4

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you just want to create a product? If so, you could also do it in the rails console on heroku with `$ heroku console`.

Comment: I want to create a ruby's scrpit which do it automatically. Do you undestand?

Comment: So you actually just want to seed your database with records, right?

Comment: Almost...Fe: I'll give you this script and you can use it for add your products. maybe it's important is on Heroku's server...

Comment: Why would you do that at all? Is there any good reason to add products via some kind of HTTP API?

Comment: Alright, then have a look at the answers, I think it's all there. Would be great if you could give some information about the request and response you're seeing from the heroku logs.

Comment: My CODE : **xxx = RestClient.post 'http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products', {
:title => 'TESTTESTTEST', :description => "MYTESTTESTTESTTEST", :image_url => "TESTTESTNULL.jpg", :price => 4.50
}
puts xxx.body**

Comment: and xxx gives: **<li>Title can't be blank</li>
        <li>Title is too short (minimum is 10 characters)</li>
        <li>Description can't be blank</li>
        <li>Image url can't be blank</li>
        <li>Image url must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.</li>
        <li>Price is not a number</li>** it gives errors because I've added validation to my app

Comment: LOGS: **T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by ProductsController#create as XML
T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"title"=>"TESTTESTTEST", "description"=>"MYTESTTESTTESTTEST", "image_url"=>"TESTTESTNULL.jpg", "price"=>"4.5"}
T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered products/_form.html.erb (6.1ms)
2011-11-02T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered products/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
2011-11-02T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 17.8ms)
2011-11-02T14:10:36+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /products] invalidate, pass**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to nest the params in the `RestClient.post` method. You're most likely looking for `params[:product]` in your action, but there won't be any data for that. I tested on your heroku app, sorry for that, but this will work (as it does for me):

```
RestClient.post 'http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products',
  :product => {
    :title => 'foobarbazfoobarbaz',
    :description => "foobarbazfoobarbaz description",
    :image_url => "foobarbazfoobarbaz.jpg",
    :price => 42.00
  }
```

Comment: Um, there has to be a "check" button left to my post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your app but I would expect you to call the POST request on http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products/ not http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products/new.

GET http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products/new would retrieve a form to create a new record.

Comment: I try do it in this way: **RestClient.post 'http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products',  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"products", 
:title => 'TESTTESTTEST', :description => "MYTESTTESTTESTTEST", :image_url => "TESTTESTNULL.jpg", :price => 4.50 }** but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried exactly like the example you posted originally but just removing the new from the end of the url?

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of `rake routes`. That will show the methods for the routes you have setup and the methods available. I suspect the /products/new will show as a GET whilst /products as a POST is what you actually want be doing.

BTW, this would have occurred locally too so it's not anything to do with Heroku.

Comment: products GET  /products(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"products"}
               POST   /products(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"products"}
   new_product GET   /products/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"products"}
  edit_product GET /products/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}
       product GET   /products/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"products"}
               PUT    /products/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"products"}
**Which one should I use and how?**

Comment: POST /products(.:format) {:action=>"create",:controller=>"products"} is the crucial one. Change your code to; RestClient.post 'http://falling-ice-5948.herokuapp.com/products', :title => 'TESTTESTTEST', :description => "MYTESTTESTTESTTEST", :image_url => "TESTTESTNULL.jpg", :price => 4.50